# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException and java.util.Scanner errors

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I keep getting an error from the compiler and i can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried a solution from [How to populate a constructor with user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442044/how-to-populate-a-constructor-with-user-input-in-java)

But I might be implementing it wrongly because it doesn't seem to work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    

import java.util.Scanner;    

public class primeNumbers {    

    private int numberCheck;    

    public primeNumbers(int numberCheck){    

        this.numberCheck = numberCheck;
        ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbersResult = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberCheck; i++) {
            if ((i % 2 != 0) && (i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 != 0) && (i % 7 != 0)) {
                primeNumbersResult.add(i);
            } else if ((i == 1) || (i == 2) || (i == 3) || (i == 5) || (i == 7)) {
                primeNumbersResult.add(i);
            } 
            /* Continue to next i */
        }    

        System.out.println("Prime numbers up to " + numberCheck + " are: " + primeNumbersResult); 
        System.out.println("Amount of prime numbers up to " + numberCheck + " is: " + primeNumbersResult.size()); 
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args){    

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int inputNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        inputNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextInt();    

        primeNumbers batch1 = new primeNumbers(inputNumber);
    }
}
```

Ik keep getting this output and error from the compiler:

```
$javac primeNumbers.java    

$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M primeNumbers
Enter a number: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at primeNumbers.main(primeNumbers.java:31)
```

Comment: There is something strange with your Java environment, it doesn't like `System.in` to the input stream from the console. Also, `inputNumber = scanner.nextInt();` and `scanner.nextInt();` look misplaced or like a copy and paste error.

Comment: Why do you have `scanner.nextInt()` in 3 places. That is unnecessary. This `int inputNumber = scanner.nextInt();` is sufficient

Comment: I don't find any error when compiled. The exact code works for me and the I get the expected output. Try using `hasNext()` to check if there is an integer available in the stream.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright. I rewrote the entire thing without methods or constructors. I cannot find any documentation on how to combine user input with methods or constructors. Alternatively, I wrote this simple thing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    

import java.util.Scanner;    

public class PrimeNumbers {     

    public static void main(String[] args){    

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int numberToCheck = scanner.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberToCheck; i++) {
            if ((i % 2 != 0) && (i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 != 0) && (i % 7 != 0)) {
                result.add(i);
            } else if ((i == 1) || (i == 2) || (i == 3) || (i == 5) || (i == 7)) {
                result.add(i);
            }
        } 

        System.out.println("Prime numbers up to " + numberToCheck + " are: " + result); 
        System.out.println("Amount of prime numbers up to " + numberToCheck + " is: " + result.size()); 
    }
}
```

My direct problem is solved, but the question of combining methods and constructors with user input remains.

Comment: Include the code in your answer.  Don't link to some (probably transient) scratch-pad site.  The link will break eventually and your answer will be meaningless.

Comment: Fine. But there is a character limit on replies so I can't copypaste my answer. :-S

Answer (score 0):

Your code also has naming conflicts like 'class name start letter has to be capital'. Once input is initialized in constructor, wrap the prime number business logic in a method for modularity.

Comment: "has to be"? That's wrong. It should be, yes, but it doesn't _need_ to be.

Comment: Okay. I did what you said about the prime number business in a method. http://tpcg.io/NCr5h6

But now I'm still getting problems that my inputNumber is non-static variable and that i cannot reference it in a static context. But, I cant seem to find out how to get around this problem.