# In java how can we pass user input to overloaded constructors?

Tags: java, user-input, constructor-overloading

Right now I am passing hard coded arguments to the constructors. I want to pass user input as argument to the constructors. Below is my code:

```
public class AddTwoNumbers {


AddTwoNumbers(int num1, int num2){
    int sum = num1+num2;
    System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);
}

AddTwoNumbers(int num1, float num2){
    float sum = num1+num2;
    System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);
}

AddTwoNumbers(float num1, int num2){
    float sum = num1+num2;
    System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);
}

AddTwoNumbers(float num1, float num2){
    float sum = num1+num2;
    System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    AddTwoNumbers addNumObj1 = new AddTwoNumbers(4,5);
    AddTwoNumbers addNumObj2 = new AddTwoNumbers(4.5f, 5.5f);
    
}
}
```

So how can I take take user input. If I use Scanner class then I am already restricting the user's choice of input that is, if I ask the user to input both integer numbers but user want one integer number and another float number. Also doing so lefts no advantage of constructor overloading.
So I am looking for a solution in which I don't want to show user multiple options to select from instead handle it by code and want to make use of constructor overloading specifically.

Comment: You can provide user four options to choose from and based on the selection call the method . Just a suggestion. For some hints check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442044/how-to-populate-a-constructor-with-user-input-in-java

Comment: You could interpret the input provided by the user and determine what type is required, e.g. if the input is "2.12" it's a float and not an int. Of course your detection should be smart enough to work also with different locale if that is important for you.

Comment: @pallavirichhariya I don't think that's what OP meant. @rich constructor overload doesn't make any sense here. You should have method overload. You can use `parseInt` before `parseFloat` in a `try-catch` block and route them to proper methods. Try it by yourself first and then tag me if you have any concerns.

Comment: Why doesnt it make sense @Aniket , suppose you have a class having main , where you are taking input from user and then there is other class where you are doing constructor overloading . OP is talking about constructor overloading and not method overloading . I think let OP confirm on what is needed here , rather than assuming things.

Comment: I am not assuming @pallavirichhariya, it is clearly a math operation and printing out the results. It's a behavior, not a construction. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @pallavirichhariya OP want it to be done by Constructor Overloading.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do much in console. you should ask the user to select witch constructor want to use and its Scanner that select what data type user enters for example:

```
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt() //will get Int
        int y = sc.nextFloat() //will get float
```